# PedigreeAnalysis Genetics

Tags: homework, molecular-genetics, genetics, epigenetics

[image]

Hello! I need help with this exercise question. I am not really sure which pedigree diagram is autosomal and which is not. But, is question b 1/2. Can someone give an explanation? Thanks very much in advance? Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 2):

According to the key given, the one shaded black on the right is autosomal and one on the left is sex linked.

Yes, the answer to b is half because Maria is XhX ans Peter is XY and so the probability of the child having this disease is 1/2.

Comment: @ApothemCyte Does this make sense ? Ask, if u need help !

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But if the the diagram on the right is concerned with an autosomal disease, shouldn't we use Gg/gg/GG notation in place of XhX (for Maria).

Comment: Also, I'm a little bit unsure as to whether the genotypes I have for the diagram are actually correct. So, a brief explanation would help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ApothemCyte, the diagrams are concerned with _both_ the autosomal disease and the X-linked disease; look at whether the person symbol is shaded on the left side or the right side.

Comment: @mgkrebbs I filled them up that way but pretty sure it's completely messed up. Can you please check to see if they are right? Thank you in advance! link: http://s837.photobucket.com/user/apothemnew/media/1557562_10152265905761177_608325393_n_zps950a5df1.jpg.html?filters[user]=138960233&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Comment: The G's seem mostly ok, but you don't know that Maria's grandmother is "GG".  The A/a's are messed up; you're treating the disease allele as recessive, but it's dominant (XA). [but then I have no formal training; I've never had a genetics course or even college biology.]

Comment: @mgkrebbs So here is my 2nd attempt. Do they look right now? (even to a person with no formal training) link: http://s837.photobucket.com/user/apothemnew/media/attempt2_zps419409e5.jpg.html

Comment: @ApothemCyte U have written Gg for peter's father but he could also be GG !